# Applescript is not inputting to excel. Should be simple?

Tags: excel, google-chrome, debugging, applescript, isbn

Its really simple. Heres the bits of my code that is doing the action.  The problem is that the info that I am trying to get off of the website is not getting inputted into the excel document.

```
<div class="book-price">
                    $53.25                </div> == $0
```

Thats what the code on the website looks like.  All I want is the $53.25 inputted.

```
set i to 2

repeat 725 times

    activate application "Microsoft Excel"

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 1
    end tell

    activate application "Google Chrome"

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using command down
        delay 1
        keystroke "https://bookscouter.com/prices.php?isbn="
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke "&searchbutton=Sell"
        delay 1
        keystroke return
        delay 10
    end tell

    set theText to getInputByClass("book-prices", 0)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set value of cell ("k" & (i as string)) to theText
    end tell

    set i to i + 1

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "w" using command down
    end tell

end repeat

to getInputByClass(theClass, num)

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of window 1
            set input to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
        end tell
    end tell

    return input
```

I think it is something very basic that I am not seeing.  The info being pasted originally are isbns.  For example 9781464139055.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial example because the value is the same on every loop, but it is working. It's basically the code you're using (only difference is the implementation of the loop and the input text).

```
on run
    set theText to "Sample Input"
    repeat with i from 2 to 300
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            set value of cell ("k" & (i as string)) to theText
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

The only thing I can guess is that your input text isn't what you expect. In looking at your code, it appears you've tried to create a function of your own called `getInputByClass`? Not sure if it's just a typo on your post or not, but that function isn't formed correctly, which may be your issue.

Here is a slight rework of your code...

```
on run
    repeat with i from 2 to 725

        tell application "Microsoft Excel" to activate -- these activate lines may not be necessary 

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "c" using command down
            delay 1
        end tell

        tell application "Google Chrome" to activate -- these activate lines may not be necessary 

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "t" using command down
            delay 1
            keystroke "https://bookscouter.com/prices.php?isbn="
            keystroke "v" using command down
            keystroke "&searchbutton=Sell"
            delay 1
            keystroke return
            delay 10
        end tell

        set theText to getInputByClass("book-prices", 0)
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            set value of cell ("k" & (i as string)) to theText
        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "w" using command down
        end tell

    end repeat
end run


on getInputByClass(theClass, num)
    try
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            tell active tab of window 1
                set input to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
            end tell
        end tell

        return input
    on error
        return "Error getting input"
    end try
end getInputByClass
```

As another note, I think there are other improvements you could make to this script. You shouldn't have to use `keystrokes` to get content from Excel and to get Chrome to open a new tab and navigate to a page. This can be done directly by scripting Excel and Chrome. If you can get away from using `System Events` and `keystroke` your script will be more stable.

For example, instead of trying to copy the content from the cell you've got selected in Excel, you can use this.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set theText to string value of selection
```

Then you can use that to create your final URL like this...

```
set MyURL to  "https://bookscouter.com/prices.php?isbn=" & theText & "&searchbutton=Sell"
```

**UPDATE !!!**

I had a little more time to run through your code and your issue is that your javascript isn't finding that class on the page, it doesn't exist.

I think you have a few more things to work out with your code, because it seems like you're going to keep opening and closing the same exact page, which is obviously a waste of energy. Also, it seems like you're continuously targeting the same data for your excel sheet the way you're grabbing the content, you aren't incrementing the number in your function call. In any event, the updated code below is similar to your code, but cleaned up and to do what I believe you're trying to do. I've moved the opening of the URL outside the repeat loop, which will significantly increase the speed of what you're doing.

**More in-depth rework of your code**

```
on run
    tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set theText to string value of selection
    set MyURL to "https://bookscouter.com/prices.php?isbn=" & theText & "&searchbutton=Sell"
    tell application "Google Chrome" to open location MyURL
    do shell script "sleep 1" -- give the tab time to load
    tell application "Google Chrome" to set newTab to active tab of window 1
    do shell script "sleep 3" -- give the page time to load

    repeat with i from 2 to 725
        set theText to getInputByClass("book-price-normal", i - 2)
        if theText as text is not "Missing Value" then
            tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set value of cell ("k" & (i as string)) to theText
        else
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    tell application "Google Chrome" to close newTab
end run


on getInputByClass(theClass, num)
    try
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            tell active tab of window 1
                set input to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
            end tell
        end tell

        return input
    on error
        return "Error getting input"
    end try
end getInputByClass
```

Comment: Still isnt working.  Even with the improvements it doesnt seem to imput any data into the cells. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KyeMoffat - I've added an update to the bottom of my answer that explains your problem.